# what is wrong with the logic of my method to add the odd numbers of an array

Tags: java, arrays, logic

I am trying to write a method that will take in the array int[] numbers and return the sum of all of the odd numbers in the array. I am not sure why it is not returning the correct value. Currently it returns "3" when it should be returning "9".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 2, 1, 5, 3, 0 };
    System.out.println(oddballsum(numbers));
}

public static int oddballsum(int array[]) {

    int sumodds = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 != 0) { sumodds = +(array[i]);}

    }
    return sumodds;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`sumodds =+ (array[i])` means "assign the value of `array[i]` to `sumodds`". The `+` and the `()` make no difference - it's semantically identical to `sumodds = array[i]`. Use this if you just want the last odd value in the array.

`sumodds += array[i]` means "increase the value of `sumodds` by `array[i]`. Use this if you're trying to sum the odd values in the array.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the error is in this piece of code...

```
if (array[i] % 2 != 0) {
    sumodds = +(array[i]);
}
```

you are not *summing or accumulating* you are just assigning the value with a positive sign

at the end, your code is just returning the last odd value found in the array...

you have to do instead something like:

```
if (array[i] % 2 != 0) {
    sumodds += array[i];
}
```

Comment: Hi @flakes... thanks for the comment... i will update inmediatly

Answer (score 0):

If you write too much code, you have more chance to go wrong, you should use java 8 Streams:

```
  int sumOdd = Arrays.stream(array).filter(t -> t%2==1).sum();
  System.out.println(sumOdd);
```

Comment: To quote user Andreas, who was paraphrasing Jamie Zawinski: "Some people, when faced with a problem, will think "I know, I'll use Java 8 streams". Now they've got 2 problems." Streams really are overkill for this - it's a simple syntactic error.

Comment: I think that also the beginner should know java Streams so they have the possibility to choose how to face a problem. They should notice when a problem could be faced in a declarative way (and use streams) and when instead the problem requires to write a list of instructions. In this case a declarative approach is more indicated.

Comment: That might be applicable if the question was 'how do I sum odd numbers from an int array' instead of asking for help for a very specific function they've already written because they're having syntactic issues.

Comment: I wrote this answer when Andy Turner had already answered and may be the OP had already solved his syntactic issues. The aim of this answer was to say to the OP "hey friend, you have another way to solve your problem, try this!". I think that this is not off topic, but I'm not an experienced SO user and if you tell me that this is off topic or overkill then I learn the lesson...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with your addition operator `=+`. It should be `+=` if you want to add and assign the new value to the same variable. Please refer below working code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {2, 1, 5, 3, 0};
    System.out.println(oddballsum(numbers));
}

public static int oddballsum(int array[]) {
    int sumodds = 0;
    for(int element : array) {
        if(element % 2 != 0) {
            sumodds += element;
        }
    }
    return sumodds;
}
```